# How can I create and reference a table in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

Can someone please share the syntax to create a table statically having certain elements and reference it? I could not find any web assembly code doing so.

Also some details like can I have multiple columns, what happens if index doesn't lie in the table etc. would be helpful?

Comment: It's not clear from the question what kind of table do you want. Is it a constant data or dynamic? Also, which language do you use for webassembly sources? Looks like you're imaging a database table, but it doesn't work this way for wasm.

Comment: @nzeemin I am not exactly sure by what you mean by source language. I am writing web assembly s-exp. Table has constant data. I'll not modify it at run time. I only want to refer based on indexes at run time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Updated for Wasm 2.0 in in 2022)

In the text format, a [table](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/text/modules.html#tables) is declared with its table type, i.e., (initial) size and element type -- currently `funcref` and `externref` are the only supported types:

```
(table $name 100 funcref)
```

Since Wasm 2.0, there can be multiple tables in a module.

A table can be initialised within a module by providing one or more active [element segments](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/text/modules.html#element-segments):

```
(elem (i32.const 0) $f1 $f2 $f3)
```

where the expression denotes the offset and is followed by a list of functions defined in the module.

Since Wasm 2.0, tables can furhter be accessed and modified through instructions like `table.get`, `table.set`, `table.size`, `table.grow`, etc.

Before 2.0, the only way to use a table was through the [`call_indirect`](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/text/instructions.html#control-instructions) instruction:

```
(call_indirect (type $t) (arg1) ... (argn) (index))
```

You can find a few simple examples in the Wasm spec test suite, e.g. here:

- https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/table.wast
- https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/elem.wast
- https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/table_get.wast
- https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/table_set.wast

A table does not have columns. As for [execution](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/exec/instructions.html#exec-call-indirect), out of bounds access causes a trap, as does accessing an uninitialised index or a type mismatch.

Comment: "currently funcref and externref are the only supported typse",  perhaps you meant `anyfunc` and `externref`?

Comment: @mallwright, I think `anyfunc` is only still used in the JS API, for historical reasons. Inside Wasm itself, it is known as `funcref`.

Comment: It seems like the two are not compatible though (see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74044249/5164339)