# Convert a Javascript function into an "funcref" for a WebAssembly.Table

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I am trying to place a Javascript function inside a [WebAssembly.Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/JavaScript_interface/Table), where the element type of the table is required to be `funcref`. The following lines can be executed in node but raise an exception when I try to put the function inside the table:

```js
table = new WebAssembly.Table({initial: 1, element: "anyfunc"})
func = function() { return 42 }
table.set(0, func)
```

The exception is:

> TypeError: WebAssembly.Table.set(): Argument 1 is invalid for table of type funcref

Is it possible to convert from a Javascript function to a `funcref`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because Wasm wouldn't be able to tell what type to assume for this function. The upcoming [`WebAssembly.Function`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/js-types/blob/main/proposals/js-types/Overview.md#addition-of-webassemblyfunction) constructor will fill that gap:

```
let func_i32 = new WebAssembly.Function({parameters: [], results: ["i32"]]}, func)
table.set(0, func_i32)
```

However, this is not yet standardised, so not yet available in browsers (at least not without turning on some flags).

Edit: The only way currently is to *import* a JS function. You can abuse that to convert a JS function into a Wasm function by funnelling it through a little auxiliary module:

```
(module
  (func (export "f") (import "m" "f") (result i32))
)
```

If you convert that module to binary and instantiate it with your function as import, then you get out a proper Wasm function:

```
let instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(new WebAssembly.Module(binary), {m: {f: func}})
let func_i32 = instance.exports.f
table.set(0, func_i32)  // works
```

Comment: I was studying the Emscripten runtime and creating a small auxiliary module is exactly the approach that they take.

Comment: Are there any browsers that currently support WebAssembly.Function behind a flag?

Comment: Chrome does, I believe Firefox as well.

Comment: I think I found it for Chrome: enable-experimental-webassembly-features specifically: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/wasm/wasm-feature-flags.h#98